# Prevent Boostrap Datepicker from displaying whole row of previous dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Sometimes, there is whole row of past dates.
How can i prevent this to happen, by removing this row if all of 7 days in a row are from previous month?

Or, is there any option for hiding them all, because I don't need them?

---

[image: first row is full of old dates, but they are visually hidden with css]

Answer (score 1):

See this

http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/98/JQuery-Date-Picker-example-to-disable-previous-dates.aspx

They have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due it is not just disabling, but totally hiding previous dates, it is a little bit tricky, but here is the answer.

So, if you want to hide all previous and next items, you can do like this with just css:

```
.day.old,
.day.new {
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```